# Is there any reason to use "from __future__ import print_function" in code that's fully Python 3 compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of relatively simple python scripts and small libraries that manage spam rejection issues for my mail server. These were all written to run under Python 2. I'm using `futurize` to convert these to run under Python 3, and ensuring, with the hashbang line, that they do so when run from the CLI or from a bash script. `futurize` inserts

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

into each script, which I understand ensures and enables Python 3 compliance.

If I have fully converted a script or library to run under Python 3 is there any reason to retain the `__futurize__ ...` import in my code?

Comment: If you're only running it in Python 3, no. futurize targets 2- *and* 3-compliant code, so isn't the right tool if you're going 3-only.

Comment: Probably [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) is what you're looking for in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes down to your audience. If there is a need to run this code in python2, you should leave them. But, if you're content with removing python2 support, go ahead and clean em up.

All the more reason to do so now sooner than later.
https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: Thank you @Kamori. This makes sense. The scripts are sysadmin tools, so the only audience is me. I'm aware of the python 2 sunset in January, which is why I'm pursuing the conversions now.